# group exact Tandem values from 2 column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 2 column latitude and longitude and want to GROUP exact match *(just)* **tandem** values on 2 columns.
***Table Rows:***

```
/* Points Table */
time    |lat    |long
113     |2.1    |5.8
114     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
115     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
116     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
117     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
118     |2.3    |5.2
119     |2.4    |5.3
120     |2.5    |5.3    -Set as Group
121     |2.5    |5.3    -Set as Group
122     |2.6    |5.3
123     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
201     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
202     |2.1    |5.6    -Set as Group
203     |2.5    |5.3
```

***Result must be:***

```
/* Points Table */
time    |lat    |long
113     |2.1    |5.8
114     |2.1    |5.6    -Grouped as 1 with first tandem time
118     |2.3    |5.2
119     |2.4    |5.3
120     |2.5    |5.3    -Grouped as 1 with first tandem time
122     |2.6    |5.3
123     |2.1    |5.6    -Grouped as 1 with first tandem time
203     |2.5    |5.3
```

I want to group just Tandem values , in above we have two time tandem of `2.1 & 5.6` values and group is splited. ( for testing can work on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d196 ). ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT time, lat, `long` FROM Points ORDER BY time");

// output header row
echo str_pad('time', 8) .'|';
echo str_pad('lat', 7) .'|';
echo "long\n";

$prevLat = $prevLong = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($row['lat'] === $prevLat && $row['long'] === $prevLong) {
        // if this row's lat and long values are the same as the
        // previous row's values, skip this row.
        continue;
    }

    $prevLat  = $row['lat'];
    $prevLong = $row['long'];

    echo str_pad($row['time'], 8) .'|';
    echo str_pad($row['lat'], 7) .'|';
    echo "{$row['long']}\n";
}
```

Here is a sample: http://codepad.org/c0SjA058

Comment: thanks, but with above query all match of two columns group as one, but on `time 23` we have new duplicate values of `2.1 & 5.6` for lat and long .

Comment: time is an a TIME-STAMP and for sample set a small number in above , time values fixed now.

Comment: OK, so the **numbers** don't necessarily need to be consecutive, but the **rows** have to be consecutive. So the two rows could be several seconds apart, but as long as there were no other rows between them, they should be grouped, is that right? I still can't really help you with that, but I would strongly suggest that you edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: @root: Check my updated answer. I thought of a solution using PHP instead of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks , I must test it .. I'l response of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT time, lat, long FROM Points GROUP BY lat, long
```